# Python can't find Pygame module on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pygame

Using home-brew I have installed pygame as homebrew says this

> "Requirement already satisfied: pygame in 
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>   (1.9.1release)"

but when I run idle3 and import pygame, python says this

```
">>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'"
```

Comment: try installing with pip instead? `pip install pygame`

Comment: thats what I did

Comment: In your question, you said you used homebrew.

Answer (score 2):

Add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` to your system path so Python knows to search here for libraries.

Here's a tutorial [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Uydjga1dXDg)

Comment: How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Added a link for a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

When running Idle3, you are likely not invoking your Python 2.7 interpreter for which you've installed `pygame`.

Does it work if you run `python2.7` from the terminal and then `import pygame` there?

Comment: if I do it with python 2  this happens,

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-

Comment: packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper